# Saving select box options content instead of value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this lines in my form

```
<%= f.fields_for :attached_vehicles do |av| %>
        <p>Select make</p>
        <%= av.select :make, options_for_select(@makes.collect { |make|[make.make_name, make.id] }), { include_blank: "Select make" }, {} %>
        ...
<% end %>
```

which renders this in html

```
<select name="diy[attached_vehicles_attributes][0][make]" id="diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_0_make">
    <option value="">Select make</option>
    <option value="1">ACURA</option>
    <option value="2">ALFA ROMEO</option>
    <option value="3">AM GENERAL</option>
    <option value="4">AMERICAN IRONHORSE</option>
    <option value="5">AMERICAN LAFRANCE</option>
    ...
</select>
```

So now it saves the value of selected option to database, and i need it to save content of selected option.
Also I can't just replace `make.id` with `make.make_name` in "options_for_select", because I need value to be id so my other dynamic select box gets right options depending on selected option.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------EDIT**

So I did as Dharam suggested

```
...
def diy_params
    params[:diy][:attached_vehicles_attributes].each_with_index do |make_id, index|
        params[:diy][:attached_vehicles_attributes][index][:make] = Make.find(make_id).make_name
    end
    params.require(:diy).permit(:title, :summary, :tip, :warning, attached_vehicles_attributes: [:make, :model, :start_year, :end_year], steps_attributes: [:step_content, add_images_to_steps_attributes: [:image]])
end
...
```

And I keep getting this error

> Couldn't find all Makes with 'id': (0, {"make"=>"12", "model"=>"XPEDITOR", "start_year"=>"2002", "end_year"=>"2010"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)

So i have tried

> ...Make.find(make_id.first.make).make_name

and multiple other things but didn't get it working, what i'm doing wrong?

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------EDIT2**

The value of make_id seems to be

> (0, {"make"=>"12", "model"=>"XPEDITOR", "start_year"=>"2002", "end_year"=>"2010"})

because it tries to find Make with it as id.

And parameters in console looks like

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Kr4yvJUPCzUagUaW1glt69HEychEz+6QyHpGjKVKQ883rTUl0pZD+9SZSaQujHgM9k7jRt0vP1WTV5fMp8xyJw==", "diy"=>{"attached_vehicles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"make"=>"12", "model"=>"XPEDITOR", "start_year"=>"2002", "end_year"=>"2010"}}, "title"=>"afaf", "summary"=>"AFSfAS", "tip"=>"FAF", "warning"=>"fdsgfsd", "steps_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"step_content"=>"gsdgsdg"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Diy"}
```

Comment: assign the content to a hidden field on submit?  or just look back up the content by value after submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before processing the `params` in your controller, you can do the following:

```
params[:diy][:attached_vehicles_attributes].each do |index, make_attributes|
  params[:diy][:attached_vehicles_attributes][index]['make'] = Make.find(make_attributes['make']).name
end
```

You can replace `Make` model with the actual model that is backing the `@models`.

Comment: Edited my question, would be nice if you could check what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: Try printing the value of `make_id` in the above `each_with_index` loop. Also provide the `params` that the controller is actually receiving. You can get the `params` from the rails development.log or from the console.